# Why struct variable goes out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers

In the below code, Why i couldn't able to access test_var from main? My assumptions are that new allocates memory in heap, so the lifetime is till the end of the main, or till you explicitly delete it. But when i try to access test_var, i get exception.

```
typedef struct test{
    int a;
    string str;
}test;

void fun1(test* test_var)
{
    test_var = new test[2];
    test_var[0].a=1;
    test_var[0].str='a';
    test_var[1].a = 2;
    test_var[1].str = 'b';
    return;
}

int main()
{
    test *test_var = NULL;
    fun1(test_var);
    cout<<test_var[0].str;
    delete test_var;            
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `test_var` is local to `fun1`, and the assignment

`test_var = new test[2];`

only has effect within the function.

You need

```
void fun1(test** test_var)
{
   *test_var = new test[2];
   ...
}
```

and in `main`:

```
test *test_var = NULL;
fun1(&test_var);
```

P. S. This isn't *really* C++ code. Raw pointers manipulation is dangerous and should be avoided. C++ has much cleaner mechanisms for doing what you're trying to do. See `std::vector`, `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

It is because in function fun1, test_var is a local variable.

```
void fun1(test* test_var)
```

Hence, any modification done in fun1 is done on local variable.

You need to do:

```
void fun1(test*& test_var)
```

Comment: That'll work, but using a pointer to pointer instead of reference to pointer (as my answer suggests) is a more conventional way.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe In C, maybe. But the question is tagged C++.

Comment: I think the least confusing option is `test* fun1();`, returning the pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: the question is tagged C++, but involves raw pointers which is not the C++ way. Your point?

Comment: @juanchopanza: that'd be `test* fun1()`

Comment: @VioletGiraffe My point is obviously that pointer to pointer is *not* a more conventional way in C++. Reference to pointer would be.

Comment: juanchopanza : In that case the correct signature is :

test* fun1()

because there is no point in test* as an argument.

Comment: @AbhishekMittal Yes, I corrected my comment. Sometimes you may need access to an original pointee, but not in this case.

Comment: The choice of pointer-to-pointer vs reference-to-pointer is divisive... the FAQ Lite encourages references, but many people and company coding standard encourage pointers (e.g. Google (me!)).  The arguments for either side tend to depend on how common certain things are in the overall body of code, so are somewhat application/library-domain specific, and the best fit for one community of programmers may not suit another.  It's not worth arguing about.

Comment: @TonyD OTOH the google C++ coding conventions are seen as a bit of a C++ joke. They certainly don't inspire any desire to do C++ at google. C++ has references for when you need references.

Comment: @juanchopanza: agree heartily regarding Google coding style in general, but on this specific issue I happen to agree with Google.  C++ certainly has references, but this isn't a situation in which *"you need references"* - both ways are functional - it's a *choice* of whether to use pointer-to-pointer as suggestive documentation - a hint that a pointer variable may (also) be an "output".  Anyway, Google was just an example of a widely known coding standard with such a rule.  Be interesting to make a list of known coding styles and survey such advice, but would take quite a while....

Comment: @TonyD The thing is, there are too many things you can do with a pointer. You can test whether it is null, you can apply `operator[]` to it, you can increment it... so passing a pointer to pointer to indicate reference to pointer isn't really that clear at all. A reference is a much simpler beast. There's less potential confusion. Of course, my view is that you shouldn't have "output parameters" anyway, in which case this point is moot.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I believe we've come full circle to my point above... *" somewhat application/library-domain specific, and the best fit for one community of programmers may not suit another. It's not worth arguing about."*.  FWIW, I upvoted this answer before my first comment and think it's a perfectly fine alternative, I'm just saying that the `**` option is not inherently/consistently incorrect or inferior.